# Check if file exists and delete it if it exists

Tags: puppet

My question is: I want to check if a file exists in the `/tmp` folder, and delete it before it starts downloading again.

Here is my code (Puppet):

```
exec { 'Download mediawiki to temp':
  cwd     => '/tmp',
  command => '/usr/bin/wget https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.27/mediawiki-1.27.1.tar.gz',    
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate as it is extremely unclear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do this ...

```
# local vars for readability
$theurl       = 'https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.27'
$tarball      = 'mediawiki-1.27.1.tar.gz'
$wget_command = "/usr/bin/wget $theurl/$tarball"
$rm_command   = "/bin/rm -f /tmp/$tarball"

exec { 'Delete mediawiki from temp':
    cwd     => '/tmp',
    command => $rm_command,
}-> 
exec { 'Download mediawiki to temp':
    cwd     => '/tmp',
    command => $wget_command,
    creates => "/tmp/$tarball",
}
```

See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html and https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html